# What is the difference between IMAPMessage.getUID() and Message-ID header?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

What is the difference between these two from java mail perspective? I can see that 2 values are not same for a particular message. So what should I consider an IMAP message's unique id?

If I need to fetch message from an IMAP server corresponding to an unique id, should I use?

```
MessageIDTerm
```

or

```
IMAPFolder.getMessageByUID()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UID` is the unique identification number of a email in a `IMAP folder`. Each mail in a folder is assigned a uid, it is you can say a index maintained by the mail folder. Whereas `message-id` is a `header` part of a email.

To understand in a simple term,
**`UID` is a unique number which cannot be duplicated within a folder**. If I copy same email twice in a folder, each will have same headers having same message-id but will have a different UID.

Other major difference is,

- UID's are assigned by a imap server
- MessageId's are set by the email
  client.

So it is always better to rely on a UID to extract the email.

Refer : [RFC - UID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1)

Comment: It is also much faster to request UIDs: it is the server's native index.  Searching for Message-ID header may degenerate to a text search of all emails.

Comment: true @Max, if you search for a Message-Id header, it will have to get the headers of each email and search within it. Its damn slow and may load the server if you have large number of mails in a folder.

Comment: UID's of messages in a folder may be changed if mailserver is restarted, updated or on some cases. To detect the issue the UIDVALIDTY of folders should be checked. If you move a message between folders, the UID values will be changed, whereas MessageID's will be kept.

Comment: @benchpresser, UID's do not change on server restart. UID's get changed if server faces some data corruption triggers and it is a rare occurence these days.

Comment: @benchpresser Yes true, the UID's will change if a mail is moved. UID's are as per folder, if a mail is moved from a folder to another, it will be treated as a new mail for a folder and will get assigned a next uid available for a folder.